# Почему бот перестает работать, если вложить его инструкции в функцию?

Tags: python, функции, telegram-bot

Закинул код для работы бота в функцию:

```
def main():
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
    .....
    ..... 
    bot.polling()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

И после этого он перестает работать. В чем ошибка?

Comment: А что делает bot.polling() - это случайно не асинхронная функция ? Т.е. main завершается же до окончания работы с бота ? Тогда ответ на поверхности - при завершении функции, все переменные в ней объявленные, выходят из области видимости и прекращают существование. И переменная `bot` так же разрушается

Comment: @Mike , а как это можно исправить? Как засунуть инструкции для бота в функцию?

Comment: Я бы переменную сделал глобальной